# Parsing different json objects from multiple urls

Tags: ios, json, swift, api

I am new to Swift and I started learning about API calls. I made *NetworkManager* class from which I fetch data from URL:

```
import Foundation

class NetworkManager {
let apiid = "?api_key=a415cfdc3dc928bd4649d310e90939e6"
func getData(from url: String, _ completed: @escaping ([String:Any]?) -> Void){
    guard let safeUrl = URL(string: url + apiid) else {return}
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: safeUrl){ data, urlResponse, error in
        guard let safeData = data, error == nil, urlResponse != nil else {
            completed(nil)
            return
        }
        if let decodedObject = SerializationManager().parse(jsonData: safeData) as? [String:Any]{
            completed(decodedObject)
        }else{
            print("ERROR")
            completed(nil)
        }
    }.resume()
}
}
```

Class is working when in closure `completed` as parameter is used some JSON model. I tried instead of JSON model parameter use `[String:Any]` so I can use any JSON model, but I only got *Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred* error.

Also, when I call function :

```
private extension HomeViewController {
func getMovies() {
    networkManager.getData(from: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing") { (movieResponse) in
        guard let movies = movieResponse?.results else {
            return
        }
        self.movieList = movies
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am getting *Type of expression is ambiguous without more context* error. (function is working when in NetworkManager class instead of [String:Any] is used NowPlayingMovieReponse (my JSON model)).

Comment: There is no *Generic parameter 'T'* in the code. And – unrelated – you can delete `[unowned self]` because `DispatchQueue` closures don't cause retain cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Function `getData`  returns `[String:Any]` while you use  `movieResponse?.results` here

```
    guard let movies = movieResponse?.results else {
        return
    }
```

inside your vc which won't work you need a model and decoder

```
class NetworkManager {
let apiid = "?api_key=a415cfdc3dc928bd4649d310e90939e6"
func getData(from url: String, _ completed: @escaping (Root?) -> Void){
    guard let safeUrl = URL(string: url + apiid) else {return}
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: safeUrl){ data, urlResponse, error in
        guard let safeData = data, error == nil, urlResponse != nil else {
            completed(nil)
            return
        }
         do {
               let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self,from:data)
               completed(res)
            }
           catch {
             print(error)
             completed(nil)
          }
    }.resume()
}
}
```

```
// MARK: - Welcome
struct Root: Codable {
    let dates: Dates
    let page: Int
    let results: [Result]
    let totalPages, totalResults: Int
 
}

// MARK: - Dates
struct Dates: Codable {
    let maximum, minimum: String
}
 
// MARK: - Result
struct Result: Codable {
    let adult: Bool
    let backdropPath: String
    let genreIDS: [Int]
    let id: Int
    let originalLanguage: String
    let originalTitle, overview: String
    let popularity: Double
    let posterPath, releaseDate, title: String
    let video: Bool
    let voteAverage: Double
    let voteCount: Int
 
}
```